# ASP.NET Eval() problem displaying two columns if Eval() != null

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval

I want to display an additional `<tr><td> <?# Eval("DataValue") %> </td></tr>` if the value of another Eval() data item is not null.

I have the following aspx:

```
   <%# Eval(TwoColumns).ToString() == null ? " " : Eval(Column2Data).ToString() %>
```

Is this possible? I get the following databinding error: does not contain a property with the name 'true'.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a little unsure of what you're asking, but try something like this:

```
<%# Eval("SomeColumn") == DBNull.Value ? " " : Eval("AnotherColumn") %>
```

If this doesn't help, edit your question and give a more detailed description of the issue and the objective.

**EDIT**

As for appending a row and a column, you can try this:

```
<%# Eval("SomeColumn") == DBNull.Value ? " " : String.Format("<tr><td>{0}</td></tr>", Eval("AnotherColumn")) %>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked but is there any way to output the value of Eval("AnotherColumn") like the following? <tr><td> Eval("AnotherColumn") %> </td></tr>

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the following:

```
<%# (Eval("TwoColumns") == null) ? " " : Eval("Column2Data").ToString() %>
```

The .ToString() method will fail if the data in the Eval is null and throw a NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%# Eval("SomeColumn").Equals(DBNull.Value) ? "" : "<td>" + Eval("AnotherColumn") + "</td>" %>
```